# Why we shouldn't use article the before importance in sentence below

Tags: definite-article

> The lack of importance of something

or

> The lack of *the* importance of something

Answer (score 0):

It is only *the lack of importance* .

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+lack+of+importance%2C+the+lack+of+the+importance&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20lack%20of%20importance%3B%2Cc0

Because it is an uncountable abstract noun.